# Can't delete a read-only file on a VirtualBox (Vagrant) shared folder between Ubuntu (guest) and Win7 (host)

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, vagrant

I have Vagrant running Ubuntu as a guest OS, on top of a Windows 7 host. When working on the **shared folder** between guest and host, if a file is read-only it can't be deleted. For example:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/temp$ touch testfile
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/temp$ chmod 555 testfile
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/temp$ ls -lA
total 0
-r-xr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Aug 22 11:36 testfile
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/temp$ rm testfile
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘testfile’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘testfile’: Operation not permitted
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/temp$
```

I also tried with **root** without success.If I change the read-only attribute (by running '*attrib -R testfile*' in Windows) then it can be deleted:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/temp$ ls -lA
total 0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Aug 22 11:42 testfile
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/temp$ rm testfile
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/temp$
```

Makes sense, the file is writable now. If the folder where the read-only file resides is not shared, I'm able to delete it:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/temp$ cd /tmp
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/tmp$ touch testfile2
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/tmp$ chmod 555 testfile2
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/tmp$ ls -l testfile2
-r-xr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Aug 22 11:44 testfile2
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/tmp$ rm testfile2
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘testfile2’? y
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/tmp$
```

I'm assuming in the first case Windows doesn't allow the VirtualBox process to remove a read-only file. Is there a way to tell Windows to allow the deletion? Maybe setting up some permission. BTW, I'm running the VirtualBox process with **elevated privileges** because I needed to be able to create symlinks (I followed this [procedure](http://ahtik.com/blog/fixing-your-virtualbox-shared-folder-symlink-error/))